# AES vs. RSA to encrypt large size of data

Tags: cryptography, aes, rsa

Can any one tell me why AES encryption Algorithm is more efficient to use than RSA Algorithm in case of encryption large block size of data ?
thanks in advance ..

Comment: Note that hybrid cryptosystems make the issue somewhat moot, because if the asymmetric encryption is expensive, you can get away with encrypting only a key for a symmetric cipher.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

RSA is very computationally expensive by comparison with AES. It involves mathematics with very large numbers, whilst AES can be implemented with relatively simple bit operations. The larger the data, the more you feel the pain.

A good compromise is to use RSA to encrypt the symmetric key that is then used in AES encryption of the larger data.

Comment: A good compromise? It's a basic way of asymmetric encryption.

Comment: Yes, I agree, but at root it is a compromise between the better performance of symmetric encryption and the key distribution ease of asymmetric encryption.

Answer (score 0):

Padding is an important issue for RSA. Note, that it is not recommended to use more than 40% of the maximum modulus length for PKCS padding and a short glimpse on the newer RSA-PSS or OAEP padding schemes will convince you, that symmetric encryption is considerably easier.